# Update from elementary OS Freya beta to stable

Tags: package-management, upgrade, elementary-os

Freya stable released toady and I have installed Freya beta 2. I want to update to stable so tried using `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`but it shows nothing. Do I have to make a clean install or is a update possible?

Comment: Did you run `apt-get update` first? What is the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: yes I did run both apt-get update and upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install the package that provides `add-apt-repository` if it's not already installed:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Next, remove elementary beta PPA and replaced it with stable.

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
```

Now remove elementary beta packages

```
sudo apt-get remove elementary-os-prerelease
```

Update Linux kernel to 3.16 similar to stable release.

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic
```

Upgrade the system and restart

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```