# No highlighted selection in Slingshot (Elementary OS Freya)

Tags: search, elementary-os, highlighting, slingshot-launcher

After logging in, when I invoke Slingshot search for the first time the highlight is there -- and it is very useful when scrolling up and down.

[image]

But after that it is absent. In all cases except during the first use after log-in, it will not be there anymore and scrolling up and down will not be visible (although it will operate in practice, only that I would not be able to see what is selected, thus making that list almost useless).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after fully updating to Freya stable following [this method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195929/32012).

It involves: removing daily sources, adding stable sources, replacing kernel 3.13 with 3.16.